React testing react-hook-form validation error message
Using "react-hook-form": "^7.45.0" I am doing the field validation. on title, just blur throwing an error as Title is required it works fine.
I am trying to write test for the same, but getting an error as:
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Title is required. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
here is my testing code:
it("should display an error if name is missing", async () => {
    setup(<TodoTestForm />);
    const titleInput = screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: /title/i });
    fireEvent.blur(titleInput);
    expect(titleInput).toHaveValue("");
    //1st approach not works
    await waitFor(() => expect(titleInput).toBeInvalid());
    //2nd approach not works
    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(screen.findByText("Title is required")).toBeInTheDocument()
    );
  });

on blur I am getting the error properly in the application. anything missing here? need to share more details, let me know.

I tried with different way. it works for me. here is the new code:
it("should display an error if name is missing", async () => {
    const { user } = setup(<TodoTestForm />);
    const titleInput = screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: /title/i });
    await user.type(titleInput, "abc");
    user.clear(titleInput);
    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(screen.getByText("Title is required")).toBeInTheDocument()
    );
  });

